# Question on the definition of a dissonant passing/neighbor tone?

Tags: theory, melody, counterpoint, species-counterpoint

I am currently trying to teach myself counterpoint following Jacob Gran's videos. When I was analyzing my exercises today, I thought of this question. If the first two notes of a dissonant neighbor(or passing) tone are over one note and the last note of the dissonant(or passing) neighbor tone is in the next measure as a consonant but has a different interval than the consonant that forms the first note of the dissonant neighbor(or passing) tone, then is it still considered a neighbor/passing tone?
Thanks!

Comment: A personal suggestion: Jacob Gran is great in a lot of ways, but leaves other aspects a bit wanting. I'd also suggest learning from Seth Monahan and Music Matters.

Comment: Ok, I will check those sources out. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Sam, welcome to Music.SE! Would you be able to give us an example, even if it's just in prose? ("Above the bass note X, Y moves down to Z...")

Comment: This question sounds a bit unclear to me. When you talk about the "notes of a neighbor tone" are you talking about the entire neighbor *figure*? That would include consonant interval, the dissonance approached by step, and the consonant resolution. A neighbor/passing tone in itself is only the dissonant note. Regardless, these tones are used very freely by composers. Just look at some of Bach's music. There are tons of dissonant notes that don't conform to a single concept of dissonance and resolution, or it's a combination of different types.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, from my understanding of your situation, that is still a passing tone. Most passing tones you find in 4 part writing are like this. A passing tone is any note that passes between two other notes that are a third apart, as long as it doesn't form an augmented second(which is forbidden anyway). In fact, a passing tone isn't necessarily dissonant. A 6th to a 5th is a passing tone just as an octave to a 7th is.